# Use HEC-DSS jython script in IDE PyDev-Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jython, pydev

I need to know how to use javaHeclib.dll in PyDev-Eclipse and run a HEC-DSS jython scritps.

I try to set javaHeclib.dll as an external libraries in PyDev-PythonPath but without results.

I try also to set file .jar as an external libraries in PyDev-PythonPath.